What is the difference between "inclusive and" and "exclusive and"
As we know that there is a difference between "inclusive or" and "exclusive or" same way can we explain the difference between "inclusive and" and "exclusive and".

I have never encountered any such terminology as "exclusive and" or "inclusive and." Would you call our normal AND operation inclusive or exclusive? What would be the truth table for its counterpart?

No such thing really.

There is no such thing as an exclusive (nor inclusive) AND gate.  That doesn't mean that you can't make up a gate with that name, though.
Since XAND should be an AND-like gate, it makes sense that 1 1 → T.  Now there are two choices.  Either 1 0 → T and 0 1 → T, but that would make it an OR-gate.  So instead, we could say that 0 0 → T, but that would make it an XNOR-gate.  And indeed, the XNOR-gate is (rarely but) occasionally referred to as the XAND-gate.
To summarize: There is no natural definition of exclusive and, and if you come up with one, it probably already has another name.
